# How to handle images in android development

Tags: android, position, imageview

All that I need is to create a simple game with animating and moving png pictures. The problem is that when I put the `ImageView` I can't to handle it by moving it to other positions(other coordinates).

If somebody could help with example, or by giving a link for good tutorial about image handling I would be very grateful. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: how do you want to move them, programmatically according to some algorithm, or by user's gestures?

Answer (score 0):

You can change you `ImageView` position dynamically using an  OnClickListener, like this:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setX(imageView.getX()+20);

        }
    });
```

This code changes your `ImageView` position by 20 on your X axis. 
You must consider that this solution is very basic and may not be suitable for your case.